# gcc linker - map all object files in an archive to a certain section

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker

In a `gcc` linker file, how do you map all functions of all `.obj`s in an archive to a certain section?

I know how to do it function-by-function inside the source file but I'd like to do it in the linker file by `.obj` name.

I found [this post in the gcc mailing lists](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-12/msg00177.html) but for me it's not working.

I modified my `.ld` by copying what the poster did...

```
.dflash_code :
  {
    *archive.dlb: // this is my archive file
  } >dflash
```

...but it didn't work.

When I add `__attribute__((section(".dflash_code")))` to a function,  amount of **overflow** the linker reports decreases so I know the linker is paying attention to the `__attribute__`.

However, I'd really like to do it for an entire archive (that's the `.dlb`).

I tried to do it just based on one `.obj` file and even that doesn't work

```
.dflash_code :
  {
    *compile.doj //my object file
  } >dflash
```

**UPDATE**

Actually, looks like it is working (kinda): it is outputting the contents of `ATI_micropython.dlb` to `.dflash_code` **except** for the **.text** sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax I tried was correct.
The problem was that in my linker file, I had a **SECTION** statement **above** the following **SECTION** statement

```
.dflash_code :
  {
    *archive.dlb: // this is my archive file
  } >dflash
```

that put all `*.text` sections in a section that was getting overfull.

Even in this errored condition, the linker produced a `.map` and examining this `.map` showed that all sections of the objects inside `archive.dlb` **except for .text** were being placed in the intended `.dflash_code`.

I moved the `.dflash_code` section above the portion that was referencing `*.text` and it now works.