# gcc - use #pragma to apply __attribute__((section(".dflash_code"))) to entire source file

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker

I really don't want to copy-paste `__attribute__((section(".dflash_code")))` to every single function in a given source file.

Is there a way, using `#pragma`, to tell compiler to apply that attribute to every function in the source file?

Comment: You have asked it yesterday. Nothing changed since then.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that question didn't involve using `#pragma`

Comment: That question was about GCC in general. This one is about specific #pragma in GCC.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this from within the source code, but you could use `objcopy --rename-section .text=.dflash_code` on the object file to get much the same effect.  See the [GNU Binutils manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/index.html) for further advice on how to use `objcopy`.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it. I'd also like to get it working using linker command [but my attempts are unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399852/gcc-linker-map-all-object-files-in-an-archive-to-a-certain-section). Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Adrian Sorry, according to everything I know, what you tried over there should have worked. I don't think anyone will be able to help you any further unless you are willing to show us your _entire_ linker script and probably also your entire Makefile and a lot more detail about the build environment.

Comment: that makes sense. If your method here works, it'll be just as good.

Comment: It doesn't work: `objcopy -I binary --rename-section .text=.dflash_code ..\orig\compile.doj .\compile.doj` gives same binary

Comment: `-I binary` tells objcopy to interpret its input as having _no internal structure_. Try it without that. If it still doesn't work, I need to know exactly what object file format you are actually using, and the host and target CPU and OS would also be helpful.

Comment: `objcopy: Unable to recognise the format of the input file ..\orig\compile.doj'`; `file format elf32-little`; target is cortex-m4

Comment: If you're using a cross compiler named `arm-something-something-gcc`, then try using `arm-something-something-objcopy` as well.  That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: I was accidentally using the `objcopy` from my windows installation instead of my ARM cross-compiler; it now works.

Comment: What's the command to modify the objects to place ALL sections in the objects in `.dflash_code` instead of just `.text`? i.e. as if in the linker-file I were mapping the entire object file to section `.dflash_code`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will not save you from having something in function declaration but actually I prefer to know that particular function (or even all) are not in the .text section. I usually `#define` something shorter like

`#define DFC __attribute__((section(".dflash_code")))`

and use it in the code. It remembers me as well when I come to the code after some time that this function has something special in the declaration.